# Error when Using queryString

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

when I try to get the Url and pass it to procedure 
it didn't passed

```
string ID = Request.QueryString["URL"];    
youtube y = new youtube();
y.URL = ID;
repCurrentVideo.DataSource = y.CurrentVideo();
repCurrentVideo.DataBind();
lblDetails.Text = "no details available about this video";
```

an error shown to me said 
Procedure or function 'currentvideo' expects parameter '@URL', which was not supplied.
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function 'currentvideo' expects parameter '@URL', which was not supplied.

and this is the stored procedure invoking code

```
public DataTable CurrentVideo() 
{
    CreateConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@URL", URL);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("currentvideo", conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: What does your request look like?

Answer (score 1):

You are never adding the SqlCommand (`cmd`) to your data adapter

try something like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@URL", URL);
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
```

or

```
CreateConnection();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("currentvideo", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@URL", URL);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
return dt;
```

Also, while we are on the topic of SqlCommands, I believe it is best to wrap them in a using statement as they are of type `IDisposable`.

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("currentvideo", conn)) {
    ...
}
```

Check out this link to see what it looks like:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlcommand

**Edit:** 
So based on your URL, you are looking for the wrong query string parameter. You need to change the assignment of `ID` to this:

```
string ID = Request.QueryString["ID"];
```

Comment: give me the same error
    Procedure or function 'currentvideo' expects parameter '@URL', which  was not supplied.

Comment: @MahmoudZakal Could you post your updated code and have you debugged to see what the value of `URL` (or `Request.QueryString["URL"];` is?

Comment: I debugged it and the value of ID still null

Comment: Okay @MahmoudZakal, what does the url that you are requesting look like?

Comment: my project is looks like youtube I have in home page videos name 
then when I click in name open the video in the ShowVideo page

Comment: @MahmoudZakal. Yes, but what does the exact url of your page look like when they click. Does it have `?URL=xyz`?

Comment: it looks like this when I click on it 
    http://localhost:1961/ShowVideo.aspx?ID=48d3891d-7bc1-4de8bb1f-6c5bc18900ba.mp4

Comment: i think it doesn't matter cause it's just like a name here is the code when i click at it it will lead me to the next page where the video should be shown `<a href="ShowVideo.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("URL") %>"><%#Eval("name")%> </a>`
and here is the video show page
 
`string ID = Request.QueryString["URL"];    
         youtube y = new youtube();
         y.URL = ID;
         `

Comment: could u add me on Facebook my name is the same name here 
then I will send the whole of the project and you fix the problem by your hand